# Mule MUnit FTP Server Schema Definition

Tags: java, mule, esb, munit

I'm trying to use the MUnit FTP Server located here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/munit-ftp-server

Several of the examples reference a ftpserver namespace but don't provide the definition of the schema. For example:

```
<ftpserver:config port="${ftp.port}" name="ftpServer"/>
```

How do you define the ftpserver namespace in the mule config? I can't seem to find an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the schema in the jar for this module, I believe it's this:

```
xmlns:ftpserver="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftpserver"
```

And the schema:

```
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftpserver http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftpserver/current/mule-ftpserver.xsd
```